# how to change array value in Laravel Controller for detaching role under team - Laratrust

Tags: laravel, view, controller, roles, detach

I sent the below value from view to controller:
in View:

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="Roles[]" value="{{$user->rolesTeams[$i]->pivot}}"/>
```

In Controller:

```
 case 'team-delete':
               $input = $request['Roles'];
                 dd($input);
```

Result:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => "{"user_id":"15","team_id":"2","user_type":"App\\User","role_id":"2"}"
]
```

now How can I make this like:

```
$user = user_id >> which should be 15
$team = team_id >> which whould be 2
$role = role_id >> which would be 2
```

so I can pass this to detach the Role within the team:

```
$user->detachRoles($roles, $team);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop array using collection or foreach

```
collect($input)->each(function ($item)use($user){

         $data=json_decode($item);
            
         $roleId=$data->role_id;
         $teamId=$data->team_id;
         $user->detachRoles($roleId, $teamId);
            
      });
```

Comment: Did not work, when I do dd($data);  it through me null;

Comment: @luayadnan.remove stripslashes from     $data=json_decode(stripslashes($item));

Comment: @luayadnan even you can use foreach instead of collect

Comment: Thank you, i will keep the collect for this section as its very small action and will use foreach on other pages.